# How to tell a gem not to be installed on JRuby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

How can I configure a gem so that it couldn't be installed on JRuby?

Comment: I'm curious... why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think in the gemspec it will be `Gem::Platform::RUBY` or something to that point for the platform value.

Comment: I'm writing a cisco acl generator. I've got some ideas to work with (such as SortedSet for IPAddr's, etc.) and BDD tools to help me doing the job. The first moved me away from 1.8 (old hash implementation) and the latter don't allow to work with BDD (sudden weird wrong subclassing) on 1.9 mode of jruby. Actually after making the working alpha I'll go back to the lab and probably find all those bugs/write compatibility proxies. But now I'd rather implement/test/put the thing into production on the least weird ruby interpreter just to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in *.gemspec:

```
s.platform = 'ruby'
```

possible platform values:

ruby

```
C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
```

ruby_18

```
ruby AND version 1.8
```

ruby_19

```
ruby AND version 1.9
```

mri

```
Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
```

mri_18

```
mri AND version 1.8
```

mri_19

```
mri AND version 1.9
```

rbx

```
Same as ruby, but only Rubinius (not MRI)
```

jruby

```
JRuby
```

mswin

```
Windows
```

mingw

```
Windows 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller)
```

mingw_18

```
mingw AND version 1.8
```

mingw_19

```
mingw AND version 1.9
```